# Email Validation with Lightbox Form on Button Click?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, email

Right now I'm working with an email unsubscribe page with the Marketing automation system Marketo. Currently, I have an email form with a button that sprouts a lightbox form asking for confirmation. The code that I pulled it from did not work with the required tag / email validation, but I altered it slightly to get that to work. Here's the issue:

When you fail to enter a valid email and click the "Unsubscribe" submit button, the lightbox form appears alongside the message that tells the user to enter a valid email. This isn't a *huge* deal, but it doesn't look very good and I'd like the lightbox form to only appear if the email is valid. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: Screencap]
.

I have limited knowledge of HTML5 so I don't really know if this is possible or how to do it. Any help is appreciated!

Also, here is the code that I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/r6psz2bq/ (main snippet):

```
<form id="mktoForm_1008"></form>
<form>
<input id="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required     size = "55px">
<button id="lightboxButton" type="submit"         onclick="submitform()">Unsubscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use Javascript's `.checkValidity()` API on the HTML 5 Email input to ensure it is valid before proceeding. I've updated your fiddle so you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/r6psz2bq/1/

Comment: This works to an extent, but once the lightbox form pops up, it immediately redirects to a blank page instead of staying on the form. Any idea?